# Error in node module package in nextJS app: SyntaxError: Named export 'x' not found. The requested module 'x' is a CommonJS module

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chart.js, node-modules, date-fns

I have following problem. I was creating a graph with chartjs and using a cartesian axis
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

For this I needed an adapter and I was installing chartjs-adapter-date-fns.
When running the application or building I get following error which comes from the node-modules folder ../node_modules/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.esm.js:7

I get this error

```
import { _adapters } from 'chart.js';
         ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export '_adapters' not found. The requested module 'chart.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'chart.js';
const { _adapters } = pkg;
```

I'm using these versions which should according to documentation be fine
https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/blob/master/README.md

```
    "chart.js": "^3.6.2",
    "chartjs-adapter-date-fns": "^3.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
```

and importing it as described with just

```
import "chartjs-adapter-date-fns";
```

Since the adapter is an external package in node modules, I cannot change it as the error suggests.

Additional information: the application itself runs with nextJs v13 but the chart component is in a separate component package inside a turbo monorepo which uses just react. Dependencies are installed in this component package.

When running e.g storybook inside the component package, I don't get an error. only in the nextjs app. Can it be something with the nextjs configuration? Can someone please help or has maybe an idea!